# How to change property source location in spring?

Tags: java, spring

In my StandardSpringConfiguration I have a value that is used to change the location of the props file (config.location).

```
@Configuration
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@PropertySource("classpath:someprops.properties")
@PropertySource(value="file:${config.location:.}/someprops.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "some.package")
public @interface StandardSpringConfiguration { }
```

Everything worked fine with spring 5.1.6.RELEASE. The issues started when I switched to spring 5.3.1.

In the past I could change the location of the prop like this:

```
 java -jar -Dconfig.location=/somepath/resources  someJar.jar --command --option AA
```

After changing the spring version the -Dconfig.location is ignored and it will use the default prop file.
I tried to get the value of config.location and print it and it prints the correct path introduced in the terminal.
Got the value like this:

```
@Value("${config.location}") String configLocation
```

Changing a single value from the prop file still works. For exapmle this will work:

```
java -jar -Ddb_user=SOME_USER  someJar.jar --command --option AA
```

Has anyone encountered such issues with more recent versions of spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

The locations must be added as an array now.

```
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:someprops.properties","file:${config.location:.}/someprops.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below props..

@PropertySource(value = "file:./filename.properties")

Comment: But this is how I wrote it.